# Entity Framework Core related data query is too slow

Tags: asp.net-core-2.1, ef-core-2.1

I have a 1-many relation between the two classes:

Parent:

```
public class Parent
{
   public string Id { get; set; }

   public virtual IList<Child> Children{ get; set; 
}
```

Child:

```
public class Child
{
   public string Key { get; set; }
   public string Value { get; set; }

   public virtual Parent Parent { get; set; } 
}
```

I need to filter Parent class instances based on a list Child class instances. The criterion is to select all the parents whose children list contains all the entries in the reference list. I have the below code:

```
IQueryable<Parent> parentsWithChildrenData = GetParentsWithChildren();

// Filter:
var referenceList = new List<Children>() { // Definition here };
parentsWithChildrenData
   .Where(x => referenceList.All(o => x.Children.Contains(o, new ChildrenComparer()))).ToList();
```

While this query is correct it takes prohibitively long to complete. How can I get this to work faster?

Comment: Apparently the `Where` criteria cannot be translated to SQL, so the filtering happens [client side](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/client-eval) after retrieving all the `Parent` records from the database. You need SQL translatable construct, which means `Contains` with custom comparer  cannot be used. Are you comparing `Child` just by Id(PK) or by some other (multiple) properties?

Comment: @IvanStoev Thanks for pointing that out. I'm comparing based on multiple properties, not just PK.

Comment: It's possible, but not easy. The comparison properties need to be known, and the whole `Where` criteria must be build dynamically using `Expression` class.

Comment: EF Core introduce the ability to handle parts of a query in-memory on a materialized collection. While it makes some things a lot easier, it's also very dangerous, as where old EF would just fail outright, letting you know that what you're trying to do cannot be translated into SQL, EF Core, will happily pull in half your database and process it in-memory. Long and short, monitor the queries your app is generating, and make sure that what's actually going to the database is what your expect.